# jquery EasyAutoComplete error when list match enabled: true

Tags: jquery, json, easyautocomplete

I am trying to use the EasyAutoComplete plugin to search a json file.  I only want to call the service once to search the json.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var player_values = (function () {
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': "http://127.0.0.1:5000/players",
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
});
return json;
})();
console.log(player_values);

var options = {
  data: player_values,
  getValue: "Player",
  list: {
        match: {
           enabled: true
      }
  }
};

$("#search-team1").easyAutocomplete(options);
});
```

When match: enabled is false, the dropdown shows the first 5 items in the json when I type.  When match:enabled is true, I get the error:

```
jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: a.search is not 
a function
at Object.method (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at f (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at e (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at a.proccess (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at a.ListBuilderService.processData (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at b (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

I've seen other posts with a similar error which was caused by multiple jquerys loading, but I don't think that's my problem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't return nulls in your results, match can't handle them.